# Component not rendering/displaying

Tags: html, angularjs

**NOTE:** This question is very similar to [Angular directive crashing browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784615/angular-directive-crashing-browser/47339136#47339136)
 but still differs in what exactly is clashing with the created AngularJS component.

So I created a very simple **nav** component and immediately after adding that component to another component's template, my browser tab was crashing.

Because it crashed right away, there was no output I could see from the console.

Here is my setup:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header_main">
        <nav></nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Nav Template**

```
<div class="dark-blue-section main-color">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header center-mobile">
        <div class="phone-wrap circled white small-btn mobile-only">Call <a send-ga-notification url="call" to="phone" mobile-only="true" href="tel:{{ $ctrl.digits }}">1.{{ $ctrl.phone }}</a></div>
        <div class="phone-wrap desktop-only">Call <a send-ga-notification url="call" to="phone" mobile-only="true" href="tel:{{ $ctrl.digits }}">1.{{ $ctrl.phone }}</a></div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-init="navCollapsed = true"
          ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-menu3"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ng-class="!navCollapsed && 'in'">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right desktop-only">
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/financing-and-insurance') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.financing-and-insurance" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Financing &amp; Insurance
            </a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/ortho-and-braces') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.ortho-and-braces" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Ortho &amp; Braces
            </a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/your-first-visit') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.first-visit" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Your First Visit
            </a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/careers') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.careers" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Careers
            </a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contact') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.contact" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Contact Us
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mobile-only">
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/locations') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.locations" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Find An Office
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/appointment') }" ng-click="clickToOpen()" uib-dropdown-toggle>
             Request An Appointment
            </a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/offers') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.offers-and-discounts" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Offers &amp; Discounts
            </a>
          </li>
          <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/your-first-visit') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.first-visit" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Your First Visit
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="mobile-only" ng-class="{ active: isActive('/careers/openings') }">
            <a ui-sref="index.careers.current-openings" ng-click="navCollapsed=true" uib-dropdown-toggle>
              Careers
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Nav Component**

```
angular
.module('common')
.component('nav', {
    templateUrl: './nav.html',
});
```

I have created many components before so this is a rare problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the name of the nav component itself was colliding with the `<nav>` HTML tag. All you have to do is rename it to something else and it will solve the issue (don't forget that you can't put dashes ('-') in the name, only camel case will work if the name is long enough).

**NOTE:**

I first tried renaming it to **navbar** which is also an HTML class in the template, but this did not cause any issues. This is weird because the similar question referenced above says the issue was a collision with a CSS class so I'm not sure why HTML classes are in the clear and not CSS classes.

Maybe someone else can chime in there.